# Formula for the total of a gradual percentage increase N times

Tags: math

What is the formula for calculating the final value after a gradual percentage increase fixed number of times?

Each next value equals the previous value increased by the same `X` percentage. And I want to calculate the final value.

**We have:**

- `I` - initial value
- `X` - percentage increase per step
- `N` - number of increases / steps

**Needed:**

`f(I, X, N)` = total value after increasing `I` by percentage `X`, `N` number of times.

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: f(I, X, N) = I * (1 + X/100)^N

Comment: @meowgoesthedog If math isn't related to programming, then what label `math` is doing here? :)

Comment: I believe `math` is for programming problems which have a mathematical theme, not for pure math questions.

Comment: One may need to ask a pure math question while programming with one of these - [Programming Languages for Mathematics](https://mathblog.com/10-great-programming-languages-for-mathematics/).

Comment: ... Which would have been a fair point had you specified said language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a simple exponential relation:

`f(I, X, N) = I * pow(1 + X / 100, N)`